# save() does not change using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code that is supposed to edit an object grabbed from a MongoDB. One of the fields is a map that has an array in it. I push to that array in the map. I log the object itself and it definitely got put into the array of the Map. It just doesn't update in the Database

Guild Model:

```
let {
    Schema,
    model
} = require('mongoose');
let Guild = new Schema({
    guildID: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    guildname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    prefix: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: "y!"
    },
    welcome_channel: {
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: null
        },
        message: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: "has joined the server!",
        }
    },
    mod_log: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: null
    },
    spaces: {
        type: Map,
        required: false,
        default: []
    }
})

module.exports = model('Guild', Guild);
```

I grab the guild object in my code later on, it isn't null or undefined.

```
let fetch_guild = await Guild.findOne({"guildid": id});
// successfully grabs the object from the db
let temp_space = fetch_guild.spaces.get(args[0]) ? fetch_guild.spaces.get(args[0]) : null;
if(temp_space.admins.includes(message.mentions.users.first().id)) return message.reply("That person is already an admin!");
temp_space.admins.push(message.mentions.users.first().id);
console.log(fetch_guild.spaces)
```

Result of that console.log:

```
Map {
  'test' => { name: 'test', admins: [] },
  'test2' => { name: 'test2', admins: [] },
  'test3' => { name: 'test3', admins: [ '500765481788112916' ] }
}
```

And I save it using:

```
await fetch_guild.save();
```

In the database, it is still an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using updateOne() of mongoose.

```
await fetch_guild.updateOne(fetch_guild);
```

Comment: Works! Thank you so much!